# Python coverage with unittesting

Tags: python, bash, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-coverage

I've written tests for my python code and want to check how much % is covered with tests, so I decided to use python coverage. But I have a problem launching it. I launch my tests with this bash command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=. && python files/test/tests.py
```

My python program is in "files" directory, and tests are in "test", so I can't launch it another way.
Using

```
export PYTHONPATH=. && python coverage files/test/tests.py
```

raises Error. How to correctly use coverage in my situation ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to use an appropriate **coverage** plugin for the unit testing framework/runner you are using:

Here are some combinations:

- [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) + [pytest-cov](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov)
- [nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.3.0) + [nose-cov](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-cov)

There are probably other tools and combinations you can use. But these two are probably the most common (*no reference*).

Answer (score 1):

```
coverage run files/test/tests.py
```